# NOT NULL constraint failed: stores_store.merchant_id

Tags: python, django, api, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using djano rest framework for designing an API for store listing, and creation. The concept of my app is a linkage between merchant and buyer. A merchant can have multiple store of various categories.I have a model of Merchant which contains about merchant information,product which contains a list of product of certain categories and Store which contains information about store.I could list the store using API and also could show the form for Store creation. However i get following error when trying to create a new store.

**IntegrityError at /api/stores/create/ NOT NULL constraint failed: stores_store.merchant_id**

**my models.py**

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

class Store(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant)
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    image = models.ForeignKey('ProductImage',blank=True,null=True)
    name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')

class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="store_category")
    store_category = models.CharField(choices=STORE_CATEGORIES, default='GROCERY', max_length=10)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username","first_name","last_name","email",)

class MerchantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = ["id","user","phone","address","city",]


class ProductImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields  =   ( 'id','imageName','image', )

class ProductSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    image = ProductImageSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=('id','image','name_of_product','description','price','active',)

class StoreCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializers()
    class Meta:
        model = StoreCategory
        # fields=["id","store_category",]

class StoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='stores_detail_api')
    store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer(many=True) 
    merchant = MerchantSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields=("id",
                # "url",
                "merchant",
                "store_categories",
                "name_of_legal_entity",
                "pan_number",
                "registered_office_address",
                "name_of_store",
                "store_contact_number",
                "store_long",
                "store_lat",
                "store_start_time",
                "store_end_time",
                "store_off_day",
                )


class StoreCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer()
    merchant = MerchantSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields=("id",
                "merchant",
                "store_categories",
                "name_of_legal_entity",
                "pan_number",
                "registered_office_address",
                "name_of_store",
                "store_contact_number",
                "store_long",
                "store_lat",
                "store_start_time",
                "store_end_time",
                "store_off_day",
                )
    def create(self,validated_data):
        store_categories_data = validated_data.pop('store_categories')
        merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
        store = Store.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for store_categories in store_categories_data:
            store_categories, created = StoreCategory.objects.get_or_create(pan_number=store_categories['pan_number'])
            store.store_categories.add(store_categories)
        for merchant in merchant_data:
            merchant, created = Merchant.objects.get_or_create(user=merchant['user'])
            store.merchant.add(merchant)
        return store
```

**Views.py**

```
class StoreCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoreCreateSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser,MultiPartParser,)
```

**Merchant object looks like this**

```
 "merchant": {
            "id": 6,
            "username": "sans",
            "first_name": "sans",
            "last_name": "bas",
            "email": "sans@gmail.com"
        },
```

Comment: Looking at the model, the order of object creation is : you should create the merchant object first and use that reference to create the store objects. 
By the way, where is your MerchantSerializer() ?

Comment: @SijanBhandari i have added MerchantSerializer().

Comment: You are trying to create a `Store` before `Merchant` so your `merchant_id` is Null at that point and that's why the IntegrityError is getting raised !  You **must** create a `Merchant` object before creating a `Store`, so that you have a NOT NULL `merchant_id`.

Comment: @KapilSachdev so i should do Merchant.objects.create(user=merchant['user']) and only create store object ?

Comment: Don't `pop` the `merchant` i.e. `validated_data.pop('merchant')`, as your store can have only one Merchant (no use of `for` statement later). Now you will have the `merchant` in your `validated_data` and then `try store = Store.objects.create(**validated_data)`.

Comment: But one merchant can have multiple store. Will that work?

Comment: I get this error now ValueError at /api/stores/create/
Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('user', OrderedDict([('username', 'Priyanka'), ('first_name', 'Priyanka'), ('last_name', 'Basnet'), ('email', 'priyanka@gmail.com')])), ('phone', 999999999), ('address', 'palpa chowk'), ('city', 'palpa')])": "Store.merchant" must be a "Merchant" instance.

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with StroreCreateSerializer. your are trying to create instance of Store without merchant thats why you are getting error. If you want to create store without merchant you need to make merchant foreign key Null true. I hope this help.

Moreover you are using add() with foreign key. add() method works with Many to Many relation.

```
class StoreCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer()
merchant = MerchantSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = Store
    fields=("id",
            "merchant",
            "store_categories",
            "name_of_legal_entity",
            "pan_number",
            "registered_office_address",
            "name_of_store",
            "store_contact_number",
            "store_long",
            "store_lat",
            "store_start_time",
            "store_end_time",
            "store_off_day",
            )
def create(self,validated_data):
    store_categories_data = validated_data.pop('store_categories')
    merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
    for merchant in merchant_data:
        merchant, created = Merchant.objects.get_or_create(user=merchant['user']['email'], default=merchant['user'])
    validated_data["merchant"] = merchant 
    store = Store.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for store_categories in store_categories_data:
        store_categories, created = StoreCategory.objects.get_or_create(pan_number=store_categories['pan_number'])
        store_categories.product.store = store
        store_categories.save()
    return store
```

To make this work you need JSON Should be like below:

```
{
   merchant:{
     "user":{
         "first_name":"ABC",
         "last_name": "xyz",
         "email":"xyz@abc.com"
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get error on here
    merchant = Merchant.objects.create(user=merchant['user'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: merchant_data is in this format OrderedDict([('user', OrderedDict([('username', 'Tush'), ('first_name', 'Tush'), ('last_name', 'Kha'), 
  ('email', 'tush@gmail.com')])), ('phone', 999999999), ('address', 'Ganesh chowk'), 
  ('city', 'Biratnagar')])

Comment: I have attached storelist api where you can see merchant object.